# Why does iPhone execute both of these if statements in a view controller .m file?

Tags: xcode, iphone-sdk-3.0

When the IBAction login is invoked it supposed to use a response from SOAP Web Services of either true or false, false meaning the user is not authorized to use the app. 
I have it using these if statements after it gets the response, but for some reason it runs both  true and false ifs.

```
{
    [soapResults appendString: string];
    NSLog(soapResults);

    if (soapResults = @"true")
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:soapResults delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Try Again",nil otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
        [soapResults release];
        soapResults = nil;
        [loginIndicator stopAnimating];
        loginIndicator.hidden = TRUE;
        loggedinLabel.text = usernameField.text;
        loggedinLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        NSLog(@"Valid Login"); 
    }
        if (soapResults = @"false")
        {
            NSLog(@"Invalid Login");
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:soapResults delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Try Again",nil otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
            [alert release];
            [soapResults release];
            soapResults = nil;
            [loginIndicator stopAnimating];
            loginIndicator.hidden = TRUE;
        }





}
```

Please Help

Answer (score 2):

There is only one equal sign in the `if` statements. This assigns the string to the `soapResults` variable which causes the if statement to evaluate the string (which will always be true).

```
if (@"true")
```

Instead, use two equal signs to do the comparison.

```
if (soapResults == @"true")
```

Some avoid this common problem by always placing the variable at the end of the comparison.

```
if (@"true" == soapResults)
```

This way if you forget the second equal sign it will cause a compilation error which is much easier to find.

**Update:** as the commentators kindly pointed out, you should not compare Objective-C strings using the == operator. Instead use the `isEqualToString` method.

```
if ([soapResults isEqualToString:@"true"])
```

Comment: [soapResults isEqualTo: @"true"] perhaps?

Comment: Good eye! Anyway, regarding comparison: better use [soapResults isEqualToString:@"true"] otherwise it will always be false (as the equal sign is not a good way to compare strings in Obj-C).

Comment: Thanks Aviad, my obj-c is rusty. I'll update the post with your mention.